# add 14 days to visit date

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

How Can I Add plus 14days into the current visit date of my tables

it tried it this code but it show many numbers lol

------------- HERES MY CODE --------------------

```
//TABLE SUPERVISORY LIST
table_supervisory_list : function (id,data){
    $(id).DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        data : data,
        columnDefs:[
            {
                "targets":[0],
                "data" : data,
                "render": function (x){
                    return `
                            <button onclick="open_patient_chart(`+`'`+x.vnote_mrno+`'`+`);" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-minier btn-round">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-in-alt"></i> `+x.vnote_mrno+`
                            </button>
                        `;
                }
            },
            {
                "targets":[1],
                "data" : data,
                "render": function (x){
                   return x.patient_lastname +' '+ x.patient_firstname +' '+ x.patient_middlename;
                 }
            },
            {
                "targets":[3],
                "data" : data,
                "render": function (x){
                    return x.vnote_visitdate + moment(x.vnote_visitdate).add(7,"days");
                }
            },

        ],
        columns : [
            { data : null, sTitle : 'Options' },
            { data : null, sTitle : 'Name' },
            { data : 'vnote_visitdate', sTitle : 'Last Supv done' },
            { data : null, sTitle : 'Next Supv due'},
            { data : 'vnote_formtype', sTitle : 'Action Required' },
            { data : 'vnote_enteredby', sTitle : 'Discipline' },
        ],
        bDestroy: true
    });
},
```

IT SHOWS 2019-04-091555344000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're trying to append a `moment` object to a string.

You don't need to do that, you can simply do:

```
moment(x.vnote_visitdate).add(14, "days").toString();
```

If you want to keep the same format, you need to do something like this:

```
moment(x.vnote_visitdate).add(14, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

[Here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is the documentation for the [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function.